# What is FL-CME and FL-SRST in router with aceess point user?

Tags: wireless

What is FL-CME and  FL-SRST in router  with access point user?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer, and also tag it with the appropriate vendor?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Cisco routers, those are VoIP configurations. CME is Communications Manager Express, and SRST is Survivable Remote Site Telephony. Neither of these has anything specific to do with 802.11 Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

They are feature licenses, thus the "FL-".  It means your router is licensed to run the telephone system functionality within your Cisco OS, called IOS.  Your router is a PBX, an IP-PBX, ...among many other things.